# What's a reasonable discount to ask for when prepaying for development services?

Tags: subcontracting, startups

I currently have a contractor working for me via an agency. The contract is rolling on a weekly basis and I can end it whenever I like.

I have suggested to the agency owner that I could prepay for development services for 3 or 6 months if a discount was offered. The owner seems to appreciate this idea as it will allow him to scale his startup agency. Neither of us has mentioned the discount percentage.

What is a reasonable starting discount to request for each of these periods?

I've read [this](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/what-discount-to-give-for-a-retainer-contract) but I'm not sure it applies here as it's 2 days a week and therefore considerably less money.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there's no set amount for any discount. It's purely a matter of negotiation between the parties. In addition, the *agency* may be good with the idea of a discount, but in rare cases the developer may not... So, they *may* need to do some internal negotiation.

Ask for what you want.. then negotiate. The worst they can say is "no".

Comment: Well, I decided to ask for what I want. I used [anchoring strategy](https://hbswk.hbs.edu/archive/when-to-make-the-first-offer-in-negotiations) to try to win the advantage and went with 30% and 40%!

Comment: Well. forget it. I might consider 5% for a contract with six months payment guaranteed, but 30 to 40% for getting the money a bit earlier? No way.